# Javascript - Delete duplicates in class

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, cloud

I have a class in parse called testItem here is a snap shot of this class

[image]

So I am trying to write a could code function to remove this. So there are not more duplicates. This is what I have tried

```
Parse.Cloud.job("removeDuplicateItems", function(request, response) {

function checkDuplicate(school) {

    var TestItem = Parse.Object.extend("TestItem");
    var testItemsQuery = new Parse.Query(TestItem);
    testItemsQuery.equalTo('school', schoolArray[i]);


    testItemsQuery.each(function(testItem) {
        var item = testItem.get('item');
        var school = testItem.get('school');
        var diningHallNum = testItem.get('diningHallNumber');

        var testItemsQueryCheck = new Parse.Query(TestItem);
        testItemsQueryCheck.equalTo ('item', item);
        testItemsQueryCheck.equalTo ('school', school);
        testItemsQueryCheck.equalTo ('diningHallNumber', diningHallNum);
        //then delete Item

}
var schoolArray = ['Union College (NY)', 'University of Albany', 'Rensselaer Polytechnic Institute'];

for (var i = 0; i < schoolArray.length; i++) {  
    checkDuplicate(schoolArray[i]);
}
}
```

but this doesn't work because it will always come true I need a way to see if this is the second time this item has come up. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks for the help in advance!!!

EDIT

If I have this data

[image]
It deletes one of the cheese items and the something item?

Comment: Dear dave needle man,
You mention that you want to delete the duplicate item via writing cloud function. However, I see that you write a cloud job. To make the question clear; you want to write cloud function or background jobs? Regards.

Comment: @kingspeech background job

Comment: you want to delete duplicate entries right, which is 2nd and 3rd?

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
Parse.Cloud.job("removeDuplicateItems", function(request, status) {
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  var _ = require("underscore");

  var hashTable = {};

  function hashKeyForTestItem(testItem) {
    var fields = ["item", "meal", "schoolMenu", "diningHallNumber", "school"];
    var hashKey = "";
    _.each(fields, function (field) {
        hashKey += testItem.get(field) + "/" ;
    });
    return hashKey;
  }

  var testItemsQuery = new Parse.Query("TestItem");
  testItemsQuery.each(function (testItem) {
    var key = hashKeyForTestItem(testItem);

    if (key in hashTable) { // this item was seen before, so destroy this
        return testItem.destroy();
    } else { // it is not in the hashTable, so keep it
        hashTable[key] = 1;
    }

  }).then(function() {
    status.success("Migration completed successfully.");
  }, function(error) {
    status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong.");
  });
});
```